# Switch to Ubuntu from Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot

I am currently using Windows XP on my laptop. I'm thinking of trying Ubuntu but if I don't like it, how hard is it to switch back? All the tech lingo is very confusing. Can I switch back and forth from Windows to Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try Ubuntu,then the best option is make a bootable Ubuntu live disk,boot from it.And then click on try Ubuntu option on startup to experience the features of Ubuntu.

Or

You can install Ubuntu on a virtual machine softwares like virtualbox,VMware and make a try on it.

Comment: Avinash told you the best possibilities - another one is to create a image (backup) of your windows xp and install ubuntu - if you dont like you can just recover your old system. clonezilla is an easy piece of software to do this (but this method is more expensive then just a live cd or a virtual machine - but if you want to try for a week with "full" support it's a good choice.